# Polynomial with variable in the exponent.

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

How do I solve a polynomial with the variable in the exponent? For the following question how would I find n? I tried to log both sides but that failed. Note: Both exponents should be negative.[image]

Comment: Is your equation $4.7992=(1.1)^n+2(1.1)^{-2n}$? (By the way, this is _not_ called a polynomial equation. A polynomial equation is only those that contain the unknown raised to a natural number.)

Comment: Substitute $x=1.1^n$ - And improve your handwriting ;)

Comment: @Arthur 1.7992 and its -n and -2n

Comment: Then follow @HagenvonEitzen's tip. It will lead you to a solution (set $x = 1.1^{-n}$).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following substitution:$$x=1.1^n$$$$4.7992=[(1.1)^n]+2[(1.1)^n]^{-2}$$$$4.7992=x+2x^{-2}$$$$4.7992x^2=x^3+2$$$$0=x^3-4.7992x^2+2$$

Use approximations from here, e.g. linear approximation.